# setup ESB Mule to eliminate point to point connection

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, esb, anypoint-studio

I am new to ESB Mule, and i am trying to figure out how to utilize not to have point to point connectin for each webservice, i want to do the following:

1-Provide an XML SOAP  webservice that will be consumed by different external clinets (XML SOAP and Restful client) and then send the message to an external SOAP webservice that is connected to ESB Mule.

2-Consume two websevices, but instead of having point to point connection, i want the client to consume web service through ESB Mule and then it will be routed to the desird external webservices.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest you start of by getting yourself a bit familiar with mule, you will find examples for your usecase here:

https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/?searchTerm=soap

AND

http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/newbie/mule-school-web-services-part-1/